# REmote LIft Actors

Tags: scala, lift, remote-access

Hi I am new to Lift , and I wanted to know if there is a remote actors library for Lift applications. I have a scenario where I have remote nodes updating information to my Lift Application that displays real-time status. I wanted to use Lift remote actors for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Akka](http://akkasource.org) to implement remote actors.

Comment: Thanks adelarsq! I was thinking of the same and also that I have remote nodes running on Akka but the problem is Lift's Comet actors which I am using for UI updation. I can't talk to Lift Comet Actors with Akka actors! Is it possible? I have doubts.... so was thinking of other possibilities. Are the remote actors for Lift not in Lift's roadmap?

Comment: You can make a bridge - an Akka Actor that forwards its messages to the Lift CometActor.